# Add skipauthorization to request object using Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular, satellizer

I'm using Satellizer to handle authentication on my app, by default Satellizer intercepts all request and adds the Authorization header.
I do all the request to my API using Restangular but I don't want to send the Authorization header in all the request I make, for example the login and signup endpoints doesn't need this header. If I add skipauthorization: true to the request object, Satellizer won't add the Authorization header. So my question is, how can I add the the skipauthorization property to some of my request using Restangular.

I tried

```
Restangular.all('signup').withHttpConfig({'skipAuthorization': true}).post(user)
```

But "withHttpConfig" is not the function I'm loooking for.

Comment: Hi, did You manage to solve this? Please post an answer if You did. I am trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write request interceptor:

```
// set full request interceptor

RestangularProvider.setFullRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {

  return {
    element: element,
    params: params,
    headers: headers,
    httpConfig: _.extend(httpConfig, {skipAuthorization: true})
  };

});
```